# C# XElement as a Predicate<>

Tags: c#

When adding XElement into a list, I'm not able to do a Find like I normally would with string or int data list. Please advise what must I do to change below to make it work as myIndexCase1 or myIndexCase2?

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.XPath;
using System.Xml;
using System.Text;

XElement x1 = new XElement("groupA", new XAttribute("Name","red"));
XElement x2 = new XElement("groupA", new XAttribute("Name","blue"));
XElement x3 = new XElement("groupA", new XAttribute("Name", "green"));
XElement x4 = new XElement("groupB", new XAttribute("Name", "white"));
XElement x5 = new XElement("groupB", new XAttribute("Name", "black"));

List<XElement> myList = new List<XElement>();
myList.Add(x1);
myList.Add(x2);
myList.Add(x3);
myList.Add(x4);
myList.Add(x5);

//We know x2 belongs to index = 1 but this syntax doesn't work ..it complains can not convert XElement to Predicates
int myIndexCase1 = myList.FindIndex(x2);

//And if I try this too also doesn't work
int myIndexCase2 = myList.FindIndex(s => x1.XPathSelectElements("group[@Name='blue']");
```

Comment: Are you looking for `myList.IndexOf(x2)`?

Comment: And, in case you're curious: A *predicate* is a function that takes a list element and returns a Boolean value. XPathSelectElements does not return a bool.

Comment: Thank you all, I have no idea predicate = boolean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FindIndex` expects a `Predicate<XElement>` not an `XElement`.

This is a predicate you could use to find the element you are looking for:

```
int myIndexCase1 = myList.FindIndex(element => element.Name == "groupA" &&
                                         element.Attribute("Name").Value == "blue");
```